# Robotium clipboard

Tags: android, robotium

I would like to test clipboard functionality by Robotium framework in my application but I have problem.
I try to open copy/paste menu but it doesn't work (I wont to see something like that [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV0Sy.png) in my test case). I tried double click on text in my EditText (by double clickOnText clickOnText) and long click on text clickLongOnText and nothing works (it works properly in my application problem is only with Robotium).

Can someone help me? What should I use?

Comment: Please check [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053240/how-to-check-if-text-is-present-in-clipboard-in-robotium-test) out, hope this can help you.

Comment: unfortunately no because I use standard android copy paste and when I click on text I see standard menu at the top of the screen. I want to cover that in Robotium test case but I can't.
All what I mentioned above not working in automated test case but when I double click on text work properly even on virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question I would cite my post from [How to change the font in android settings using Robotium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221651/how-to-change-the-font-in-android-settings-using-robotium)

> I'm certainly sure that `Robotium` doesn't provide this feature.
>   `Robotium` is an instrumentation test framework, which is close to
>   your app's UI , so if your app doesn't provide this feature in its own
>   interface, `Robotium` won't do it.
>
> Although, lately I'd read about Google's UI test framework
>   `uiautomator` and it seems to have this feature. To prove that
>   assumption read this
>
> [Android: Espresso test for lock screen/main screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351750/android-espresso-test-for-lock-screen-main-screen)
>
> http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html
>
> So please try to find out more about this `uiautomator` framework
>   which might be great addition to your existing `Robotium` tests.

Yes, post talks about `Espresso`, but instead of it you would use `Robotium`. I've already found these frameworks quite similar